# PHP Connection with DB2 in Windows running Apache Server

Tags: php, database, apache, db2

```
$hostname = "localhost";
$database = "RUTHLESS";
$user = "ruthless";
$password = "guessit123";

$conn_string = "DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER - DB2COPY1};HOSTNAME=$hostname;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=$user;PWD=$password;DATABASE=$database;";

$conn = db2_connect($database, $user, $password);

if ($conn) {
   echo "Success";
   db2_close($conn);
} else {
   echo "failed ".db2_conn_errormsg();
}
```

The above program does not display anything on the browser window??? The code seems to be stuck on db2_connect() function.

Answer (score 0):

Open the php.ini file in a text editor and add the following lines
Enable the PDO extension and PDO_ODBC driver:

```
extension=php_pdo.dll
extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
```

Note: On Windows, the PDO_ODBC driver uses the Windows ODBC Driver Manager to connect to database systems. To access DB2 database systems with PDO_ODBC on Windows, you must install the IBM® DB2® Driver for ODBC and CLI.
    To enable the ibm_db2 extension:

```
extension=php_ibm_db2.dll
```

Enable PHP support in Apache HTTP Server 2.x by adding the following lines to your httpd.conf file, in which phpdir refers to the PHP install directory:

```
LoadModule php5_module 'phpdir/php5apache2_2.dll'
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir 'phpdir'
```

For more details check this 
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.udb.apdv.php.doc%2Fdoc%2Ft0023667.htm

Comment: Still the problem exists... :(

Comment: no error message or exception is shown... Just the body is blank... It is now showing anything at all... The page in browser is completely blank....

Comment: ok, debug your code for example check where code is breaking put die('test'); aftert this line    $conn = db2_connect($database, $user, $password); and see you output if still blank then in my opinion you have problem in your configuration. did you restart your server after above mentioned changes? and have you checked link also?